# Kubernetes multiple databases

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, microservices

I'm going to develop a Java microservice application and as I discovered it is an anti-pattern to share a database between microservices, I have a question.

Lets say I have 3 microservices and want to create 3 separate PostgreSQL databases. Do I have to create each service with different exposed port for 3 PostgreSQL images?

Comment: you could have single postgres server with 3 databases such that postgres host and port remain same but user creds and database name is different.

Comment: What @shubham_asati mentioned can also work, but if you follow domain driven design and are sure that your microservices are falling under one umbrella (just separating business logic) I'd recommend to use one Database and 3 separate tables (or documents whichever DB you are using). This will help to simplify when your microservices are using common configurations for e.g. lets say from Consul / Helm